# Are the memory barriers correct for this lock?

Tags: c++, locking, atomic, spinlock

Is this correct? And am I correct in assuming that applying the memory ordering on the `std::atomic_flag` does NOT provide synchronization for general-purpose locks?

```
#include <atomic>

class Spinlock
{
public:
    Spinlock(): f(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

    void lock()
    {
        while(f.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed));
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
    void unlock()
    {
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        f.clear(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag f;
};
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I feel like an `std::atmoic_thread_fence` IS necessary for a general-purpose lock, and that applying `memory_order_acquire` on the `test_and_set` and `memory_order_release` on the `clear` is not enough, but I'm also not sure.

Comment: This isn't a mutex, it's a spinlock. Why are you trying to write your own mutex class?

Comment: @davmac Huh, I always assumed that a spinlock was just a type of mutex. I'll change the wording.

Comment: @davmac To better understand atomic operations? Why does it matter why I'm writing it?

Comment: A spinlock is technically a kind of mutex (I suppose), but you don't usually want to use one when you can use a "real" mutex. As to "why does it matter" - because, if you're trying to re-write something that already exists, you generally shouldn't. Is "to better understand atomic operations" actually a question? You have a question mark after it.

Comment: @davmac It was more of an inquiry as to why it matters. What if I were trying to write my own threading library? I'm not, but what if I was? It wouldn't be relevant to the question, as the question is about the lock itself. Anyway, I'm writing it as a "learning experience"

Comment: @davmac: People who say "a spinlock is not a mutex" are confusing interface with implementation, which is also known as "bad engineering". Of course a spinlock is a kind of mutex. And this is a perfectly legitimate question for someone trying to learn the details of C++11 memory barriers.

Comment: @Nemo, my point was mainly that you shouldn't re-implement the wheel; that this was purely an exercise in trying to understand memory barriers was not clear at that point, hence the question ("why are you trying to write your own mutex class"). I have already acknowledged that spinlocks are a kind of mutex. Please actually read the comments thoroughly before you throw insults.

Comment: @mebob "I'm writing it as a "learning experience"" - that's fine, I was just asking. If we can understand your motivation we can tailor our answers accordingly.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to understand libc++ is to reimplement it. And there are improvements that can be made. Not that the library writers aren't brilliant -- they are -- but they have to work under annoying constraints like ABI compatibility.

For example, sizeof(std::mutex) is about 40 bytes on my implementation. (gcc 7.4.0.) A spinlock can be 1 byte. There are use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is to use `test_and_set(memory_order_acquire)` and `clear(memory_order_release)`. But I suspect you know that already.

According to the standard section 29.8 [atomic.fences] (2):

> A release fence A synchronizes with an acquire fence B if there exist
>   atomic operations X and Y, both operating on some atomic object M,
>   such that A is sequenced before X, X modifies M, Y is sequenced before
>   B, and Y reads the value written by X or a value written by any side
>   effect in the hypothetical release sequence X would head if it were a
>   release operation.

In your code, A is the fence in your `unlock()` function; X is the `clear()`; Y is the fence in your `lock()` function; and B is the `test_and_set()`. So your code meets the requirements of this section of the standard and therefore your `unlock()` and `lock()` functions are properly synchronized.

Comment: So, just to check my understanding, the implementation is correct but it isn't necessary to use explicit fences? I could just apply the ordering as arguments to the `test_and_set` and `clear` and get equivalent semantics for the lock?

Comment: Yes. I figured you already knew that and were specifically asking about how fences work :-). You can just do test_and_set() as an acquire and clear() as a release and get the same effect.

Comment: Ha, I guess I was just getting some weird unfounded superstition about doing it like that. I have an incomplete understanding of how all the memory ordering stuff in C++ works, but now I understand a little more! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Overall it is correct. 
Since you used 'std::memory_order_relaxed' in the test_and_set function then without the 'atomic_thread_fence' call there is nothing that would prevent reordering of operations done before and after the Mutex::lock. Since it is expected that 'Mutex::lock' acts as a memory barrier then the call to 'atomic_thread_fence' becomes necessary. But I believe the same effect could be achieved by using 'std::memory_order_acquire' in the 'test_and_set function'.
See this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag

Comment: I am trying to answer his question if 'atomic_thread_fence' is necessary or not. I believe it is necessary because of the usage of std::memory_order_relaxed.

Comment: His question -- asked in the title and again in the body -- was "is this correct"? I cannot tell whether your answer is "yes" or "no".

Comment: @Nemo There are two questions, not just "is this correct?". The statement "the call to atomic_thread_fence seems necessary" seems to me to be a "yes" to the second question.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, but what I meant to ask was if using the `atomic_thread_fence` was necessary over using `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` as an argument to the atomic operations.

Comment: Also, I intended to write `memory_order_relaxed` in the code example on `clear`. I just corrected that.